# Create a looping search

Tags: excel, vba

I have row data dumped in sheet named "PDFtoEXCEL" and inside this data I have tables that I want to extract into my sheet named "CCE_Lab"

To find the tables I do a search for a keyword that is only available in those tables I am looking for, I search for "Compressibility2"

Then i offset from the active cell which was automatically selected by the search to copy the table and its title from sheet "PDFtoEXCEL" to sheet "CCE_Lab"
After the paste I offset one row below the pasted table

**After that is where I need the help, I want the macro to search for the next table with keyword "Compressibility2" and paste it from sheet "PDFtoEXCEL" to sheet "CCE_Lab" one line below the first paste.
I want this search loop to keep going on until all my tables in sheet "PDFtoEXCEL" are copied and pasted to sheet "CCE_Lab"**

This is the code I currently have, looking for your help to complete it:

```
Sub CCE_Tables_Group()
'
' CCE_Tables_Group Macro
' grouping CCE tables from PDF input
'

'
    Sheets("PDFtoEXCEL").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2546, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="Compressibility2", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, -4).Range("A1:F25").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CCE_Lab").Select
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(26, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) to example may help.Also pl try to avoid Activecell.

Comment: Hello Ahmed AU, I have looked through the link you sent and tried to understand it and came up with possible solution using For Each and Next. but i get a compiler error saying: Next without For. What do you suggest?

Comment: this is the coding:
    Sheets("PDFtoEXCEL").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    For Each c In ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Cells
    If c.Value = "Compressibility2" Then
    Cells.Find(What:="Compressibility2", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, -4).Range("A1:F25").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CCE_Lab").Select
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(26, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Next

Comment: @MohamadAlkhatib: your error is because you have `If c.Value = "Compressibility2" Then ` but there is no *End If* before the `Next`

Comment: @MohamadAlkhatib: Also, please see [Excel VBA - How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) - your code will run much more quickly if you don't directly activate cells, but just reference the cells or their values

Comment: @MohamadAlkhatib: for example, instead of ` Sheets("PDFtoEXCEL")` you could use `With  Sheets("PDFtoEXCEL") .... End With` and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "tables" aren't Excel tables, then obviously you can't solve this by conveniently looping over `ListObjects`.

So instead try a `Do-Until` loop, and loop through all `Find` results until you're back at your first one (it should loop back to your first result eventually).

Something like:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CopyMatchingTablesToSheet()

    Const NUMBER_OF_ROWS_BETWEEN_PASTES As Long = 1

    With ThisWorkbook
        Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
        Set outputSheet = .Worksheets("CCE_Lab")
        'outputSheet.Cells.Clear ' Uncomment this if you want to clear the sheet before pasting.

        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Set sourceSheet = .Worksheets("PDFtoExcel")
    End With

    Dim findResult As Range
    Set findResult = sourceSheet.Cells.Find(What:="Compressibility2", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If findResult Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Could not find a single 'Compressibility2' in worksheet '" & sourceSheet.Name & "'." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Code will stop running now.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = outputSheet.Cells(outputSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow > 1 Then lastRow = lastRow + 1 + NUMBER_OF_ROWS_BETWEEN_PASTES

    Dim firstAddressFound As String
    firstAddressFound = findResult.Address

    Dim addressFound As String
    Do
        With findResult.Offset(-2, -4).Range("A1:F25") 'Magic numbers used in offset.
            .Copy
            outputSheet.Cells(lastRow, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats ' If you want to paste "everything", then use something like xlPasteAll below
            lastRow = lastRow + .Rows.Count + NUMBER_OF_ROWS_BETWEEN_PASTES
        End With

        Set findResult = sourceSheet.Cells.FindNext(findResult)
        addressFound = findResult.Address

        DoEvents ' Get rid of this if you want.
    Loop Until (firstAddressFound = addressFound) Or (findResult Is Nothing) ' This second condition is likely unnecessary

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves my macro and save me huge time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the below will do what you're after.

In short, we loop through every `table` on `"PDFtoExcel"` sheet, check if it contains the sub-string and then handle the copy-paste from there.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CopyMatchingTablesToSheet()

    With ThisWorkbook
        ' Uncomment the line below if you want to clear the sheet before pasting.
        ' .Worksheets("CCE_LAB").Cells.Clear

        Const NUMBER_OF_ROWS_BETWEEN_PASTES As Long = 1

        Dim table As ListObject
        For Each table In .Worksheets("PDFtoExcel").ListObjects

            ' table.Range (below) will search the table's body and headers for "Compressibility2"
            ' If you only want to search the table's body, then change to table.DataBodyRange
            Dim findResult As Range
            Set findResult = table.Range.Find(What:="Compressibility2", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not (findResult Is Nothing) Then
                ' Again, if you only to copy-paste the table's body,
                ' then change below to table.DataBodyRange.Copy
                table.Range.Copy

                With .Worksheets("CCE_LAB")

                    Dim lastRow As Long
                    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                    If lastRow > 1 Then lastRow = lastRow + 1 + NUMBER_OF_ROWS_BETWEEN_PASTES

                    ' If you want to paste "everything", then use something like xlPasteAll below
                    ' But I think xlPasteAll will create another Excel table on your CCE_Lab sheet
                    ' with some new, unique name -- which can make the document a mess.
                    ' Your call.
                    .Cells(lastRow, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                End With
            End If

        Next table

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: One question: in this macro should my tables in the searched sheet be (Formatted as Tables)? because they are not. I need after finding the search keyword to move 2 rows up and 4 columns back then copy from that position 6 columns A to F and 25 rows this range will cover one table in the searched sheet and paste it in the result sheet then leave one empty row in the result sheet. Then the search loop repeat to fine the next table in the searched sheet. How to code that? @our man in bananas

Comment: @MohamadAlkhatib, Yes, this macro requires your tables to actually be Excel tables. Since that's not the case with your file, I've posted another suggestion as a second, separate answer. Try it out if you want.